# Torque on a rotating axle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, rotational-kinematics

[image]

The problem is from the book Classical Mechanics by David Morin. Here's my attempt
One of the principal axes will be along the rod ($\hat x_1$) and other two will be passing through the center perpendicular to each other ($\hat y_1$ and $\hat z_1$). The angular velocity comes out to be $\dot{\theta} \hat x_1+\Omega cos \theta \hat z_1+ \Omega sin \theta \hat y_1$. I am not able to get how to proceed futher,should the net torque be zero? Please help me out with this problem

Answer (score 1):

Euler equation gives you the torques $\vec{M}$ required for the motion of rotating bodies.

You can choose a frame rotating with the body around the vertical axis $\hat{y}_1$ with angular velocity $\Omega$. Within this frame you have 2 wheels with constant angular momentum $\omega I$ along the horizontal axis $\hat{x}_1$ pointing to the right. Both wheels also have the constant angular momentum $\Omega I_y$ around $\hat{y}_1$ pointing up.

$$
\vec{M} = \frac{d\vec{K}}{dt}+ \vec{\omega}_{frame} \times \vec{K} =\frac{d}{dt}
\begin{pmatrix}
2\omega I\\
\Omega I_y\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
+
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
\Omega\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
\times
\begin{pmatrix}
2\omega I\\
\Omega I_y\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
-2\omega \Omega I
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The result shows you that a torque of $-2 \omega \Omega I$ is required to keep the wheels on the ground. Assuming each of the two wheels has a mass $m$, then the torque provided by the right wheel is $-m g l$ (pitching point would be the point of contact between the left wheel and the ground, the right wheel provides the torque through its mass and the distance $l$ to the pitching point). If $2 \omega \Omega I> m g l$, then the provided torque is not sufficient anymore to maintain the given motion and the right wheel will lift off.

Comment: This is confusing me aren't the principal axes fixed with respect to body? in that case  $\Omega$ will not always be in direction of $\hat y$ as it will be rotating with body  so we will have to take component of  $\Omega$ along the principal axes. I have taken the same coordinates and getting a completely different angular velocity

Comment: The principal axes do rotate with the body. However choosing a frame rotating with the principal axes would over-complicate the problem, because $I_y = I_z$. Either way you will obtain the same result. If you choose a frame rotating with the principal axes, keep in mind to transfer the moments back to a frame parallel to the ground, because the torque $-ml$ is acting in this frame. BTW: I realized later that I chose a different coordinate system: $\hat{x}_1$ to the right, $\hat{y}_1$ to the top, $\hat{z}_1$ comes out of the sheet.

Comment: little typo, it should be: "keep in mind to transfer the _external torques_ back to a frame parallel to the ground"

Comment: Another typo: the torque through gravitation is obviously $mgl$ and not $ml$